# Finding n-grams in tm does not work following package updates

Tags: r, tm, rweka

I had some text-mining code in R using the tm package that was working well.  Then, I updated both R along with the tm and R-Weka packages.  Now, the code does not work, and I am not sure why.

My original guide for the code came from: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/6127413

Neither this code (linked above) nor my code (below) gives the desired results at this point.  When my code executed successfully (under previous versions of the packages),
it provide n-grams that involved a specific, key word.  It would also provide an ordered list of words according to their distance from the key word within the set of n-grams.

There are two specific problems:

1. One tm feature that is generating an error each time (that may be causing the next/second problem) is the PlainTextDocument.  That line of code is:

eventdocs <- tm_map(eventdocs, PlainTextDocument)

The next line of code is:

```
eventdtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(eventdocs)
```

When trying to create the document-text matrix (eventdtm), the code gives the error:

Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 
  'i, j' invalid

I have updated *everything*, including java, and still this error is arising.

I remarked-out the PlainTextDocument code as the text I am using is already in .txt format, because I found some who said this step was not necessary.  When I do this, the document-text matrix is formed (or seems to be formed accurately). But I would like to resolve this error because I previously encountered problems when that line did not execute.

2. But, regardless of this, there seems to be a problem in the formation of the n-grams.  The first block is the most suspect to me.  I am not sure the NGramTokenizer is doing what it should.

That code is:

```
span <- 4 
span1 <- 1 + span * 2 
ngramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = span1, max = span1))
dtmevents <- TermDocumentMatrix(eventdocs, control = list(tokenize = ngramTokenizer))

#find ngrams that have the key word of interest
word <- "keyword"
subset_ngrams <- dtmevents$dimnames$Terms[grep(word, dtmevents$dimnames$Terms)]

subset_ngrams <- subset_ngrams[sapply(subset_ngrams, function(i) {
tmp <- unlist(strsplit(i, split=" "))
tmp <- tmp[length(tmp) - span]
tmp} == word)]

allwords <- paste(subset_ngrams, collapse = " ")
uniques <- unique(unlist(strsplit(allwords, split=" ")))
```

The uniques set of words is just the key word of interest, with all of the other high-frequency collocates removed (at this point, I know the code is not working).  Any help or leads would be appreciated.  It took a *long time* to get things working originally.  Then, with the updates, I'm out of action.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you test just the NGramTokenizer on a variable storing some text?

Comment: Hi Yannis....Thank you for the reply and question.  I checked the functionality of NGramTokenizer (the line of code below), and it seemed to give the correct results for the document-text matrix:  

 ngramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = span1, max = span1))

It seems that where things are not working is: 

 word <- "keyword"
 subset_ngrams <- dtmevents$dimnames$Terms[grep(word, dtmevents$dimnames$Terms)] 

subset_ngrams just gives a single n-gram with the keyword.  
Thanks...Alan

Comment: the `sapply` part is a bit strange. I will try to have a look but I would use the `quanteda` package for those kinds of tasks.

Comment: I tried the linked gist and it works for me. The `subset_ngrams` doesn't only contain a single ngram. One note is that you need to use `content_transformer`with `tm_map` i.e. `eventdocs <- tm_map(eventdocs, content_transformer(PlainTextDocument))`

Comment: Thanks, Yannis.  Still working on it here.  I tried inserting the content_transformer code in the way you illustrated with all of the tm_map codes, but did not have any success.  I also tried it with the gist linked code and that didn't work either.  I think the PlainTextDocument transformation is needed, but the tm author (Feinerer) indicated in the March revision of tm that this function now collapses all of the documents into one, which I think is causing problems in then creating the dtm (dimensions are all off).  Any other ideas?  Thank you!..Alan

Comment: RESOLVED: I was able to get my original code (posted in my question) to run as needed.  To do this, I reverted to a previous version of R (3.2.3).  I also reverted to tm version 0.6-2.  I had to reinstall slam (sparse light weight arrays and matrices) version 0.1-37.  With this, my code ran as it did originally.  Lesson learned: not all updates automatically move one forward (at least in my humble case).  Thank you again, Yannis for responding.  Your posts sparked the idea that I should try my previous package versions.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad our discussion led you to find a solution. I couldn't reproduce the problem though as I probably have slightly different configuration. Please post your solution as answer for SO users to benefit from it. I'm inclined to believe that quanteda will calculate collocations in C and thus be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

It's tm package version issue.
You need to install version 0.6-2.
Solutions:

1. Code - faster:

`require(devtools)
install_version("tm", version = "0.6-2", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")`

2. If that doesn't work, download the package and install it manually.